# Environment profiles with @Qualified implementations of services?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have an interface called `MyService` and several implementations that I've added `@Qualifier` to, such as A, B, etc.  I'm trying to set up environment profiles such that I can select which one with a simple property file.  Right now I have to do something like this:

```
@Value("${my.service.impl}")
private String myServiceImpl;

@Bean
public MyService myService() {
  if (myServiceImpl.equals("A")) {
    return new MyServiceA();
  }
  else if (myServiceImpl.equals("B")) {
    return new MyServiceB();
  }
  // ...
}
```

But ideally I'd be able to just do something like this:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("${my.service.impl}")
public MyService myService;
```

However as far as I can find @Qualifier doesn't parse expressions.  Does it not support expressions? More importantly, is there a cleaner way than an if/else to tell Spring which one to load?

Comment: Just in case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: As far as I've determined if anyone looks at this in the future, in Spring 4 there's no support for expressions in qualifiers, and there's also not a cleaner way to do this.